# RS232 serial-port sniffer bytes out of order

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

This is a simple RS232 serial-port sniffer that logs byte by byte with direction indication.
There are two sides A and B and packet structure is [STX] [DATA] [ETX] [LRC(check-sum)], then other side replies with [ACK] if [LRC(check-sum)] is correct. The problem is that bytes with probability of ~50/50 get out of order.

**OUTPUT OK**

Bytes are in correct order [STX] [DATA] [ETX] [LRC] and then [ACK] from other side

```
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;STX
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;00
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;88
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;11
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;3D
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;5D
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;AF
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;79
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;D3
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7629776>;A;5F
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;EB
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;0E
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;0A
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;4C
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;54
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;50
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;43
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;ETX2
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;A;44

<2019-12-03 14:49:23.7785776>;B;ACK2
```

**OUTPUT NOT OK**

Bytes out of order, [STX] [DATA] [ETX], then [ACK] from other side, and only [LRC] after. This is not possible as [ACK] is only returned if [LRC] is correct. Otherwise, return would be [NAK]. The logger must be buggy there.

```
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;STX
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;50
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;4E
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;2D
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;53
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;30
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;37
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;50
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;8E
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;22
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;59
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;DLE
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;33
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;19
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;A0
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;19
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;12
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.8877778>;A;DLE
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.9033779>;A;33
<2019-12-03 14:49:23.9033779>;A;ETX1

<2019-12-03 14:49:23.9033779>;B;ACK1

<2019-12-03 14:49:23.9033779>;A;72
```

**CODE**

We open 2 COM ports and start logging thread:

```
        OpenComPortA();
        OpenComPortB();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(AddToFile);
```

COM port opening and worker startup:

```
        private void OpenComPortA()
        {
            _sideAManager = new SerialWorker();    
            _sideAManager.OnException += OnExceptionSideA;   
            new Thread(() => _sideAManager.Start(_sideASettings)).Start();
        }
```

```
        public void Start(ComPortSettings settings)
        {
            _side = settings.SideName;
            EventHandler<Exception> onException = OnException;
            try
            {
                CreateCom(settings);
                OpenCom();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                onException?.Invoke(this, ex);
            }

            Task.Factory.StartNew(ReadComPort);
        }
```

Main process of waiting for byte to read, then adding read argument to concurrent queue:

```
        private void ReadComPort()
        {
            while (ComPort.IsOpen)
            {
                EventHandler<Exception> onException = OnException;
                try
                {
                    byte byt = (byte)ComPort.ReadByte();
                    ThreadSafe.Queue.Enqueue(new ReadArgument
                    {
                        Side = _side,
                        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"),
                        Value = ControlCharacters.Convert(BitConverter.ToString(new[] { byt }))
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    onException?.Invoke(this, ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Queue that is appended by A, B sides and read by logwriter:

```
        public static class ThreadSafe
        {
            public static ConcurrentQueue<ReadArgument> Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<ReadArgument>();
        }
```

Spinning loop, waiting for incoming data to log, thread started at the very first code fragment above:

```
        private void AddToFile()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (ThreadSafe.Queue.TryDequeue(out ReadArgument ra))
                {
                    _serialLogWriter.Write(ra);
                }
            }
        }
```

Log write:

```
        private readonly StreamWriter _writer;
        private string _lastSide;

        public SerialLogWriter(string path, bool append)
        {
            _writer = new StreamWriter(path, append);
        }

        public void Write(ReadArgument ra)
        {
            lock (_writer)
            {
                if (_lastSide != null && _lastSide != ra.Side)
                {
                    _writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }

                _writer.Write($"<{ra.Time}>;{ra.Side};{ra.Value}{Environment.NewLine}");
                _writer.Flush();

                _lastSide = ra.Side;
            }
        }
```

Any insights on synchronization error in code?

**EDIT**

It seems that it is more hardware error, not software.
Sniffer software was used on oldschool laptop, that has idle CPU usage of 50-70%, and uses 1,7~/2 RAM on 64-bit WIN7. I couldn't reproduce such byte synchronization error on my development environment with the same initial code posted above.

Tried to optimize my code with several suggestions:

- Moved processing/conversions to log writer thread;
- Eliminated mix of TAP and Threads, left only Threads and set priority for writer to lower than COM readers.
- Got rid of tight loop by replacing ConcurrentQueue to BlockingCollection;

Result:

- No changes on development environment which is pretty much high-end setup;
- Still same byte synchronization error occurances on old laptop;

I guess it is easier to simply upgrade my hardware then.

Comment: Mixing TAP with plain old Thread is _not_ a good idea. Didn't read further than that, tbh. I'd fix that first, then see if the issue is still there.

Comment: 3 More things: 1. You have seemingly one single thread writing, so why locking the _writer? 2. `lock` should be on a dedicated object (that's what MS recommends), while I don't think it's a problem here. 3. `AddToFile` - that's a very short spin without even wait. Very bad idea. Maybe consider using a [blocking Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). Or maybe a Channel.

Comment: Retracting my comment partly about TAP. Effectively you are starting a Threadpool Thread inside a Thread. Still not a good idea.

Comment: * [Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=netcore-3.0)  of course only if you're on dotnet core 3.0+.

Comment: No, I'm on .NET framework 4.7, WinForms

Comment: You have a race condition. `A` sends its message, and `B` receives and verifies it.  Meanwhile your sniffer program "reads" the message from its system buffer byte by byte, and reports info on each byte (which consumes time).  Sometimes the sniffer cannot finish its report on the last byte from `A` before the response from `B` is received and reported.  IOW your sniffer report is not synchronized with what is on the wire, and in fact ends up sufficiently delayed to produce interleaved data.

Comment: Any suggestions for a better approach?

Comment: The information your program stores in the log/queue is expensive to generate, e.g. timestamp & input-byte to string conversions.  Storing unconverted binary values would be faster.  Perform conversion when there is time to spare, i.e. while outputting the log.

Comment: You also need to ensure that the log writer is a lower priority than the main process(es) for acquiring data.  The log writer must hold the lock for only the time it takes to copy data from the log.  The lock must not be held while it performs I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will inform how it goes after update.

Comment: Updated original post with the results.

Comment: There is another software optimization that you have not tried: make the read() syscall as efficient as possible, meaning request/fetch more than just one byte at a time.  Upgrading the hardware is the "solution" favored by people who don't know how to write efficient software.

Comment: How can i wait for more than one byte if there are cases when both sides send their data at the same time. Then it goes like A B A B A ...

Comment: *"How can i wait for more than one byte ..."* -- Don't know what's available in C#, but POSIX permits a program to read (actually fetch) all the bytes already received, instead of the expensive/slow byte-by-byte you use.